# Solr dying silently without any sort of error

Tags: solr

I am doing a bulk import via Spark (over 120,000,000 docs) to Solr 6.1 with one core only on one single machine. It starts with:

`SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms128g -Xmx180g"`

so 128 Gb as starting memory till 180 Gb for the JVM.
In the `solrconfig.xml` file I have changed this:

```
<!-- removed update logs
        <updateLog>
            <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
            <int name="numVersionBuckets">${solr.ulog.numVersionBuckets:65536}</int>
        </updateLog>
        -->

<autoCommit>
            <maxDocs>${solr.autoCommit.maxDocs:1000000}</maxDocs>
            <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
        </autoCommit>

<autoSoftCommit>
            <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime>
        </autoSoftCommit>
```

However Solr looks dying silently. I have searched for "error/exception" in the logs but nothing.

However I have found a strange line in the logs:

```
/opt/solr/server/logs/solr_log_20161108_2145:2016-11-08 18:17:59.609 INFO  (commitScheduler-14-thread-1) [   x:mydata] o.a.s.u.DirectUpdateHandler2 start commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=true,prepareCommit=false}
```

I don't get why soft commit and open searcher are "true".

How can fix it or at least find out what makes it crash?

**UPDATE**

Here is a log when I commit 10 lines from a CSV file:

```
2016-11-09 08:46:10.263 INFO  (qtp1435804085-140) [   x:mydata] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [mydata]  webapp=/solr path=/update/csv params={}{add=[0c0e883e-89e0-4051-97a2-a244af3fe323, bc78d0f3-5bbe-4467-b51d-34218e28afd0, 24feaecf-d0bf-4fb3-82ff-52d6d3d6359f, ec281476-0e84-4c20-a90d-f5394045a0c9, 54768e68-2514-4662-ad2f-237cc88b4e71, fece234d-470e-4cf8-9103-744eedc00074, b2db067c-5b8e-4b48-b2dd-3f8192d8023b, 0a3a5829-e513-4de8-8b43-662a44af34c5, 9c38bcc0-2377-42e3-8835-93c999e995f8, fcd235c1-d11f-4fca-ae64-0052c0c6b347]} 0 43
2016-11-09 08:46:13.874 INFO  (qtp1435804085-140) [   x:mydata] o.a.s.u.DirectUpdateHandler2 start commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false,prepareCommit=false}
2016-11-09 08:46:14.042 INFO  (qtp1435804085-140) [   x:mydata] o.a.s.c.SolrDeletionPolicy SolrDeletionPolicy.onCommit: commits: num=2
    commit{dir=NRTCachingDirectory(MMapDirectory@/data/solr/cores/mydata/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@4be8e307; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0),segFN=segments_42m,generation=5278}
    commit{dir=NRTCachingDirectory(MMapDirectory@/data/solr/cores/mydata/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@4be8e307; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0),segFN=segments_42n,generation=5279}
2016-11-09 08:46:14.042 INFO  (qtp1435804085-140) [   x:mydata] o.a.s.c.SolrDeletionPolicy newest commit generation = 5279
2016-11-09 08:46:14.045 INFO  (qtp1435804085-140) [   x:mydata] o.a.s.s.SolrIndexSearcher Opening [Searcher@759dc815[mydata] main]
2016-11-09 08:46:14.046 INFO  (qtp1435804085-140) [   x:mydata] o.a.s.u.DirectUpdateHandler2 end_commit_flush
2016-11-09 08:46:14.047 INFO  (searcherExecutor-21-thread-1-processing-x:mydata) [   x:mydata] o.a.s.c.QuerySenderListener QuerySenderListener sending requests to Searcher@759dc815[mydata] main{ExitableDirectoryReader(UninvertingDirectoryReader(Uninverting(_5jti3(6.1.0):C7038890) Uninverting(_5k0wd(6.1.0):C8257243) Uninverting(_5k82u(6.1.0):c1884381) Uninverting(_5kds9(6.1.0):c3063817) Uninverting(_5k5c1(6.1.0):c1376845) Uninverting(_5ki6j(6.1.0):C7977387) Uninverting(_5km5t(6.1.0):c1389379) Uninverting(_5kuvw(6.1.0):C7774961) Uninverting(_5ltts(6.1.0):C8363860) Uninverting(_5l7al(6.1.0):C8202044) Uninverting(_5lmbm(6.1.0):C7559846) Uninverting(_5l80g(6.1.0):c219576) Uninverting(_5lw9d(6.1.0):c1776541) Uninverting(_5m675(6.1.0):c6563395) Uninverting(_5lf6c(6.1.0):c523032) Uninverting(_5lmhy(6.1.0):c336604) Uninverting(_5m1tp(6.1.0):c1218207) Uninverting(_5mdko(6.1.0):c1848209) Uninverting(_5m98t(6.1.0):c1054658) Uninverting(_5m61y(6.1.0):c552591) Uninverting(_5m7v4(6.1.0):c947312) Uninverting(_5m92r(6.1.0):c471612) Uninverting(_5macc(6.1.0):c644159) Uninverting(_5mbo6(6.1.0):c909037) Uninverting(_5mdem(6.1.0):c511430) Uninverting(_5mfyj(6.1.0):c1041738) Uninverting(_5mefp(6.1.0):c373980) Uninverting(_5mefh(6.1.0):c137376) Uninverting(_5mgnt(6.1.0):c437679) Uninverting(_5mga7(6.1.0):c163097) Uninverting(_5mhqn(6.1.0):c907489) Uninverting(_5mhyz(6.1.0):c184742) Uninverting(_5mjnk(6.1.0):c393719) Uninverting(_5mirb(6.1.0):c310351) Uninverting(_5mjhh(6.1.0):c1109235) Uninverting(_5ml6g(6.1.0):c171704) Uninverting(_5mkkr(6.1.0):c925799) Uninverting(_5mloo(6.1.0):c308985) Uninverting(_5mmkw(6.1.0):c855873) Uninverting(_5mloe(6.1.0):c16005) Uninverting(_5mmkt(6.1.0):c21430) Uninverting(_5mlow(6.1.0):c22566) Uninverting(_5mmus(6.1.0):c49455) Uninverting(_5mlov(6.1.0):c18885) Uninverting(_5mmuy(6.1.0):c69606) Uninverting(_5mlo5(6.1.0):C16421) Uninverting(_5mmuu(6.1.0):c68416) Uninverting(_5mmkq(6.1.0):c10353) Uninverting(_5mmkr(6.1.0):c11267) Uninverting(_5mmks(6.1.0):c11998) Uninverting(_5mmod(6.1.0):c12312) Uninverting(_5mmof(6.1.0):c22240) Uninverting(_5mmoe(6.1.0):c16571) Uninverting(_5mmut(6.1.0):c39317) Uninverting(_5mmuv(6.1.0):c30787) Uninverting(_5mmnm(6.1.0):c4373) Uninverting(_5mmuq(6.1.0):c3817) Uninverting(_5mmur(6.1.0):c8112) Uninverting(_5mml7(6.1.0):C928) Uninverting(_5mmla(6.1.0):C1008) Uninverting(_5mmkx(6.1.0):C953) Uninverting(_5mmol(6.1.0):C965) Uninverting(_5mml6(6.1.0):C926) Uninverting(_5mmuz(6.1.0):C10) Uninverting(_5mmv0(6.1.0):C10)))}
2016-11-09 08:46:14.047 INFO  (searcherExecutor-21-thread-1-processing-x:mydata) [   x:mydata] o.a.s.c.QuerySenderListener QuerySenderListener done.
2016-11-09 08:46:14.047 INFO  (searcherExecutor-21-thread-1-processing-x:mydata) [   x:mydata] o.a.s.h.c.SuggestComponent buildOnCommit: locationd
2016-11-09 08:46:14.047 INFO  (searcherExecutor-21-thread-1-processing-x:mydata) [   x:mydata] o.a.s.s.s.SolrSuggester SolrSuggester.build(locationd)
2016-11-09 08:46:15.533 INFO  (searcherExecutor-21-thread-1-processing-x:mydata) [   x:mydata] o.a.s.c.SolrCore [mydata] Registered new searcher Searcher@759dc815[mydata] main{ExitableDirectoryReader(UninvertingDirectoryReader(Uninverting(_5jti3(6.1.0):C7038890) Uninverting(_5k0wd(6.1.0):C8257243) Uninverting(_5k82u(6.1.0):c1884381) Uninverting(_5kds9(6.1.0):c3063817) Uninverting(_5k5c1(6.1.0):c1376845) Uninverting(_5ki6j(6.1.0):C7977387) Uninverting(_5km5t(6.1.0):c1389379) Uninverting(_5kuvw(6.1.0):C7774961) Uninverting(_5ltts(6.1.0):C8363860) Uninverting(_5l7al(6.1.0):C8202044) Uninverting(_5lmbm(6.1.0):C7559846) Uninverting(_5l80g(6.1.0):c219576) Uninverting(_5lw9d(6.1.0):c1776541) Uninverting(_5m675(6.1.0):c6563395) Uninverting(_5lf6c(6.1.0):c523032) Uninverting(_5lmhy(6.1.0):c336604) Uninverting(_5m1tp(6.1.0):c1218207) Uninverting(_5mdko(6.1.0):c1848209) Uninverting(_5m98t(6.1.0):c1054658) Uninverting(_5m61y(6.1.0):c552591) Uninverting(_5m7v4(6.1.0):c947312) Uninverting(_5m92r(6.1.0):c471612) Uninverting(_5macc(6.1.0):c644159) Uninverting(_5mbo6(6.1.0):c909037) Uninverting(_5mdem(6.1.0):c511430) Uninverting(_5mfyj(6.1.0):c1041738) Uninverting(_5mefp(6.1.0):c373980) Uninverting(_5mefh(6.1.0):c137376) Uninverting(_5mgnt(6.1.0):c437679) Uninverting(_5mga7(6.1.0):c163097) Uninverting(_5mhqn(6.1.0):c907489) Uninverting(_5mhyz(6.1.0):c184742) Uninverting(_5mjnk(6.1.0):c393719) Uninverting(_5mirb(6.1.0):c310351) Uninverting(_5mjhh(6.1.0):c1109235) Uninverting(_5ml6g(6.1.0):c171704) Uninverting(_5mkkr(6.1.0):c925799) Uninverting(_5mloo(6.1.0):c308985) Uninverting(_5mmkw(6.1.0):c855873) Uninverting(_5mloe(6.1.0):c16005) Uninverting(_5mmkt(6.1.0):c21430) Uninverting(_5mlow(6.1.0):c22566) Uninverting(_5mmus(6.1.0):c49455) Uninverting(_5mlov(6.1.0):c18885) Uninverting(_5mmuy(6.1.0):c69606) Uninverting(_5mlo5(6.1.0):C16421) Uninverting(_5mmuu(6.1.0):c68416) Uninverting(_5mmkq(6.1.0):c10353) Uninverting(_5mmkr(6.1.0):c11267) Uninverting(_5mmks(6.1.0):c11998) Uninverting(_5mmod(6.1.0):c12312) Uninverting(_5mmof(6.1.0):c22240) Uninverting(_5mmoe(6.1.0):c16571) Uninverting(_5mmut(6.1.0):c39317) Uninverting(_5mmuv(6.1.0):c30787) Uninverting(_5mmnm(6.1.0):c4373) Uninverting(_5mmuq(6.1.0):c3817) Uninverting(_5mmur(6.1.0):c8112) Uninverting(_5mml7(6.1.0):C928) Uninverting(_5mmla(6.1.0):C1008) Uninverting(_5mmkx(6.1.0):C953) Uninverting(_5mmol(6.1.0):C965) Uninverting(_5mml6(6.1.0):C926) Uninverting(_5mmuz(6.1.0):C10) Uninverting(_5mmv0(6.1.0):C10)))}
2016-11-09 08:46:15.534 INFO  (qtp1435804085-140) [   x:mydata] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [mydata]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={commit=true}{commit=} 0 1660
```

Comment: How about posting the last 25 ines in the log file, just in case...  Also, I'd try dropping that number in the solrconfig.xml for autoCommit down just in case that helps.  Maybe by an order of 10 down to 100,000?  Finally - are you seeing any docs in your collection when you restart Solr?  If yes - then you are getting "throughput" even though it's crashing.  If no, that suggests the crash is happening before the docs can be written (which also argues for trying a smaller number as a quick test)

Comment: yes, it commited ~90M out of ~120M records. I have updated one "suspicious" line from from the logs which is unclear to me.

Comment: Does your syslog / messages, etc. say anything? If solr / the JVM just disappears without further trace, it might be because of an OOM kill from the underlying OS.

Comment: I cannot see any errors in the system logs.

Comment: So as a short-term fix, I might try committing far less that a million at one time.  That will probably increase the amount of time it takes to run but may avoid hitting some memory constraint that is messing up the process.  I understand that's not a "solution" in terms of understanding exactly what is happening, but I assume your primary need is to get get it done.

Comment: Also, you might try hitting the solr-user list - there are folks on there who may know more...  http://lucene.apache.org/solr/resources.html